# Reloading a page after an error, redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a button to reload the page back to its original state if the user passed bad input.

I tried recalling the action but it doesn't have any effect on the page.

```
refreshOnError = () => {
    this.props.fetchData('AAA')
}
```

I also tried doing the following:

```
refreshOnError = () => {
    window.location.reload()
}
```

This returns this error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.reload')`

This is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchData} from '../Redux/actions/postdata';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataInput:'',
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('AAA')
    }
    callFetchData = () => {
        this.props.fetchData(this.state.dataInput);
    }
    refreshOnError = () => {
        this.props.fetchData('AAA')
        //window.location.reload()
    }
    render() {
        const { fetching, warningVisibility} = this.props;
        if(fetching) {
            return(
              <View>
                  <ActivityIndicator />
              </View>
            )
        } else if(warningVisibility) {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>Check your internet connection</Text>
                    <Button title='Refresh' onPress={this.refreshOnError}/>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <ScrollView>
                    <SearchBar 
                        placeholder="Type your name"
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({dataInput:text})}
                        onCancel={()=>this.setState({dataInput:''})}
                        onSubmitEditing={(text) => this.callFetchData({dataInput:text})}
                        value={this.state.dataInput}/>
                </ScrollView>      
            )
        }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      fetching: state.dataInfo.fetching,
      warningVisibility: state.dataInfo.warningVisibility
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchData})(Home);
```

Is there a way to refresh the page and get it back to its state before the user created the error?

Also, I am using `redux-saga`, if there is a way to create a saga to handle refresh that would be great. Thank you!

**UPDATE:** my saga call

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import {call, put, takeEvery, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as service from '../../Services/api';
import * as actions from '../actions/postData';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

function* fetchData(){
  try{
    yield put(actions.requestData());
    const [ post, comment ] = yield ([
      call(service.getUserPost),
      call(service.getUserComment)
    ])
    yield put(actions.receiveData( post.data, comment.data));    
  } catch(e){
    yield put(actions.receiveDataFailed());
  }
}

function* watchFetchData(){
  yield takeEvery(types.FETCH_Data, fetchData);
}

function* showWarning(action){
  yield delay(1500);
  yield put(actions.hideWarning());
}

function* watchReceiveDataFailed(){
  yield takeEvery(types.RECEIVE_DATA_FAILED, showWarning);
}

export default function* dataSaga(){
  yield fork(watchFetchData);
  yield fork(watchReceiveDataFailed);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `sagas` generator code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to reload the page back to original state, therefore you should create a `reset()` action that restores the reducers to its `initialState`,

**Actions.js**

```
export function reset () {
  return {
    type: RESET
  }
}
```

**Reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {/* Define your Initial State here */}

function mainReducer(state = initialState, action) { //<== Bind the initialState here
 switch (action.type) {
   case RESET:
     return initialState;
 ...
}
```

**Sagas.js**

```
function* fetchData(){
  ...
  catch(e){
    yield put(actions.reset()); // <== Reset to InitialState on Failure
    yield put(actions.receiveDataFailed());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. However, when I try this, it gets stuck on `<ActivityIndicator />` and its forever loading. I even set `fetching:false` in the initialState

Comment: Okay . try checking tracking the values of `fetching` using `redux-logger` or `console`. Also update the question with the latest codebase along with relevant reducers and actions.  If the codebase is reproducible then you may post a [snack](http://snack.expo.io)

Comment: It seems there was a typo here `yield put(actions.receiveDataFailed()` which I made that caused no response. The second issue was to create another state and change `fetching:false` as my `initialState` needed to have `fetching:true`.  So passing `return refreshState` in the reducer helped.  It is not what I fully wanted, as it doesn't reload, but is more like a return button. But its a solution which helped. Thank you